# JS -> PHP: Getting 'null' symbol in the beginning of the string on server-side

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to send data from contact-form (JavaScript) to remote back-end (PHP). I need to save data as JSON file on serve-side.

The problem is:
When I the following code on server-side:

```
$x = json_decode($string);
$y = json_encode($x);
file_put_contents($file, $y);
```

I receive 'null' symbol in the beginning of the string.

It looks like this:

```
null{"name":"name","lname":"lname","email":"email@emaol.rue","pwd":"123","gender":"female"}
```

Both sources have utf-8 encoding.

The client-side JS looks like this:

```
function getFormData() {
        var sendData = new FormData();
        var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

        XHR.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
            console.log('Yeah! Data sent and response loaded.');
        });

        XHR.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
            console.log('Oups! Something goes wrong.');
        });

        XHR.open('POST', 'http://example.com/backend.php');
        XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        XHR.send(JSON.stringify(sendData));
    }
```

The server-side looks like this:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $file = "store.json";
    $fo = fopen($file, 'at');

    $str = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $decoded = json_decode($str);
    $encoded = json_encode($decoded);


    fwrite($fo, $encoded);
    fclose($fo);
?>
```

My question is:
I need to append each new form-data received as new line in JSON file on server. This strange 'null' symbol makes the file messy. Why it happens and how to get rid of it?

---

**Solved:**
The issue is solved.
The problem was in extra request-type "OPTIONS" which was made automatically prior main "POST" request. Each time the server received "OPTIONS" request it tried to json_decode() it. Of course, it had "null" result.
I've simply added IF statement on server-side which checked the request-type is "POST" request.

Comment: Could you please console.log(sendData); in your client side and post it here @alex_t

Comment: Because this symbol is invisible in original string. But php treats it like real symbol. Actually it causes empty lines when I append each new form-data to the file.

Comment: FormData {name: "Name", lname: "LName", email: "email@emaol.rue", pwd: "Qwerty123", gender: "male"}

Comment: Make a json your self with the form values and parse it. You need to name the json array with some name. Otherwise it will show you null. See here , the data is the array name.  Data {name: "Name", lname: "LName", email: "email@emaol.rue", pwd: "Qwerty123", gender: "male"}

Comment: Thank a lot John. I'll try your way.

Comment: One more thing bud , First of all  try naming your form, then check the response whether it's giving null or your form name .. then try the above solution @alex_t

Comment: Ok. I didn't really use name-tags in this form because all logic is bound to ID-s. Thanx).

Comment: I've pasted wrong data here. It was raw object. Here's stringified data. 
Which is actually sent: 
{"name":"Name","lname":"LName","email":"email@emaol.rue","pwd":"Qwerty123","gender":"male"}